# adding existing weblogic server to eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jakarta-ee, weblogic

### !

while i was trying to add weblogic server to eclipse , 
i went into : new server wizard -> download additional servers adapter 
* chosed oracle web logic tools -> next
 i got this  **message**

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Oracle WebLogic Server Tools 2.1.1.201209271754 (oracle.eclipse.tools.indigo.weblogic.feature.group 2.1.1.201209271754)
  Missing requirement: Oracle WebLogic Server Tools 4.3.1.201209271754 (oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic 4.3.1.201209271754) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore [2.7.0,2.8.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Oracle WebLogic Server Tools 2.1.1.201209271754 (oracle.eclipse.tools.indigo.weblogic.feature.group 2.1.1.201209271754)
    To: oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic [4.3.1.201209271754]
```

how can i solve it ? 
any help will be apreciated

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to download [Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html). It provided Oracle's Middleware for developers who looking addition weblogic server.

Comment: actually i am using "Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 2" , thanks anw

Comment: @indian You can load previous released from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-archive-1716547.html.